# SSRS Code and Automated Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am currently trying to automate reports using SSRS in SQL Server 2008, requiring little to no user input at all.

I have the queries already to acquire the data, but they require datetime parameters which are retrieved from an invoices table in the database.

Is there any way to automate this, without requiring user input? I'd like to have these reports fire off every Monday morning without prompting. We also have an internal web site which is used for administrative work, written in ASP and C#, that I can use in conjunction in need be.

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this. In each report you can set a query to retrieve parameter values and you can also specify a query for the default values.

So

1. Add a parameter and have that parameter be passed to your stored proc that gets your data
2. Set the available and default values for that parameter to a sql query that returns the value you need for the parameter.

You'll need to do this for each parameter. Then as long as all parameters in the report have default values the report will run without prompting for parameters.